# Confusion about omitted "object" with 有する

Tags: particle-は, particle-が

I just read this clause (as a definition of 独特):

> そのものだけが有していること。

I first understood it in a way, that "[Something] has only this thing.", instead "Only this thing has [something]".
Now I'm kind of doubting my own language skills, and whether my confusion is *justified*. I think if I would have written the same sentence as:

> そのものだけは有していること。

or

> そのものだけはあることが有していること。

Do my versions sound natural as well? If not, why not?
Also, how would you have translated "[Something] has only this thing." with "something" being omitted and without being ambiguous?

Answer (score 1):

Since こと (circumstance/issue) is a word with little animacy, そのものだけはあることが有していること doesn't really make sense.

そのものだけは有していること is ambiguous if そのもの is the subject or the object.

"[Something] has only this thing." can be expressed as （何かが）これだけを有する(こと).